# Connecting to Oracle using oci_connect

Tags: php, oracle, oci8, tnsnames

I am trying to make a successful Oracle connection using PHP.

Here is how my connection string looks:

```
<?php
   $conn = oci_connect("USER", "PASS", "LOSINGMINDHOST");
   if (!$conn) {
       $e = oci_error();
       error_log(trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR));
   }

   oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Getting the following error:

```
Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

Which points to the line with oci_connect.

I am on a Windows Server 2019.

The php.ini file has been updated to include the following:

```
extension=oci8_12c
```

I have confirmed that the dll file above is indeed in the ext folder listed as:

```
php_oci8_12c.dll
```

Not sure why the php.ini file does not include the full name of the dll file.

The server has been installed with Ocale 12g instant client 64bit.

We have confirmed a connection using ODBC Data Source Administrator client using tnsnames.ora file.

We also have a listener.ora file the looks like this:

```
PROD_MIR =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = ttp.world)(PROTOCOL = TTP)(Host = LOSINGMINDHOST)(Port = 1524))
  (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = ttp.world)(PROTOCOL = TTP)(Host = LOSINGMINDHOST)(Port = 1551))
  (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = ttp.world)(PROTOCOL = TTP)(Host = LOSINGMINDHOST)(Port = 1538))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = PROD)
)
)
```

We added the TNS_ADMIN path to the environment variables on the server.

We have already restarted the services and even rebooted the server.

Comment: The 3rd parameter, "losingmymindhost" is the entry in tnsnames.ora?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte - I updated my question to include a description of the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: Use `PROD_MIR` instead

Comment: @FelippeDuarte - I am no longer getting the error.  You, sir, have saved my life.

Comment: No problem @JohnBeasley . I wrote an answer to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) says:

> oci_connect ( string $username , string $password [, string $connection_string [, string $character_set [, int $session_mode ]]] ) : resource

> connection_string
> Contains the Oracle instance to connect to. It can be an » Easy Connect string, **or a Connect Name from the tnsnames.ora** file, or the name of a local Oracle instance.

It was your case, use the proper tnsnames.ora Connection name.